# Nested each() loops skipping a value

Tags: jquery, html

I have 5 values stored in localstorage like so:

*localStorage.setItem('medium**0**_highscore' , "Test_user, 99999, 99:59, 9" );*
*localStorage.setItem('medium**1**_highscore' , "Test_user1, 99999, 99:59, 9" );*

and im trying to add them to a table using the following code:

```
   $('#medium tr').each(function(k) {
     var info2 = localStorage.getItem("medium" + k + "_highscore");
     var t_info2 = info2.split(",");
     $(this).find('td').each(function(j) {
       $(this).html(t_info2[j]);
     });
   });
```

My problem is the first value stored is skipped, i included a bunch of alerts to find why and i found that the index "k" on the first each loop jumps to 1 right after the `var t_info2 = info2.split(",");` line runs ignoring the following code.

im sure its something really simple but im not seeing it.

Comment: seems like your code works. maybe it's a problem with your localstorage https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVRxqB?editors=1010

Comment: It looks like you're right, i have no idea what it is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your table has a first `<tr>` that is a header row with `<th>` tags? If so, try to use `$('#medium tr:has(td)')` instead of `$('#medium tr')`.

With the behavior that you describe, it is the only possibility. The first iteration is in this row, because it has no `<td>` tags, de code after `var t_info2 = info2.split(",");` will do nothing.

Comment: Better to use `$('#medium').find('tr:has(td)')` to help out the right to left sizzle engine parsing.